# niceScroll set div scroll always from bottom for chat box

Tags: jquery, css, nicescroll

I want to set div scroll always from bottom for chat box like showing in image below, 
Other solution also acceptable.

[image]

Comment: please show attempts so far

Comment: `$('div2scrollID').scrollTop($('div2scrollID').get(0).scrollHeight);` try this.

Comment: [USE A TUTORIAL](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931) or [USE A PLUGIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/9-crazy-jquery-chat-chat-box-plugins/)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it like this:

Let's suppose:

```
<div id="chat-scroll-container">
    <div id="chat-content">
        ... your messages ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You can do it like this:

```
$('#chat-scroll-container').getNiceScroll(0).doScrollTop($('#chat-content').height());
```

If you don't want to use any animation, do it like this:

```
$('#chat-scroll-container').getNiceScroll(0).doScrollTop($('#chat-content').height(), -1); // -1 is the animation duration
```